# Find constants in expression of the form $y = ax^b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

So I have a real system that for a given setting, x, returns a value, y.
These values appear to follow (with some limits) the form of $y = ax^{-b}$ -  could also be expressed as  $y = \frac{a}{x^b} $.

How many data pairs do I need to be able to work out what $a$ and $b$ are, and how do I work them out? Excel seems to have no trouble, but I also have no idea how it gets there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need more than two pairs to do a least square fit.

Transform the equation to 
$$\ln{y}=a-b\ln{x}$$

Then you can use usual least square method to find the parameter $a,-b$, using the pairs $(\ln{x_i},\ln{y_i})$.